# Getting data from website without URL

Tags: php, web-scraping

I am working on a project which needs to extract data from website by parsing its html and getting the content out of title tag and meta description.I am able parsing that data from normal website, but in this matter the website is only can be access using IP address as the URL.Is it possible to be extract and what solution can be use?

Comment: an `url` is just a way to translate an`ip address` into something human rememberable. So using a direct IP should just work fine

Answer (score 1):

A URL doesn't need a domain name, something like http://127.0.0.1/test.php is a valid url and all scraper should work with this correctly.

This requires the website to respond on requests to the ip-based url. Those on private servers or very big sites might do, sites from ordinary shared hosters usually don't as they host multiple sites with the same ip.

Comment: Let say the website that I want to access is private website that only can be access from internal. Is it still I can use web scraping on it?

Comment: The scraper must have access to it. If the scraper is on the internet and can't access your internal website, then no, it's not possible. But that isn't a programming issue but a networking one.